# clojure's `into` in common lisp

Tags: clojure, common-lisp, sequence

clojure has a handy `(into to-coll from-coll)` function, adding elements from `from-coll` to `to-coll`, retaining `to-coll`'s type.

How can this one be implemented in common lisp?
The first attempt would be

```
(defun into (seq1 seq2)
  (concatenate (type-of seq1) seq1 seq2))
```

but this one obviously fails, since `type-of` includes the vector's length in it's result, disallowing adding more elements (as of sbcl), though it still works for list as a first arg
 (while still failing for empty list).

the question is: is it possible to make up this kind of function without using generic methods and/or complex `type-of` result processing (e.g. removing length for vectors/arrays etc) ?

i'm okay with `into` acting as `append` (in contrast with clojure, where `into` result depends on target collection type) Let's call it `concat-into`

Comment: Does `into` have a functional contract? The naming makes me guess it mutates the first argument.

Comment: @Sylwester, since collections in clojure are immutable (in general), it's semantics is 'make new collection of arg1 type with all arg1 elements adding all arg2 elements into it'. But in the scope of this question the mutating variant would also work, since it is more about generic result type 'inference'

Comment: I would use [FSET](https://common-lisp.net/project/fset/Site/FSet-Tutorial.html), which define immutable functions as well as conversion functions; there is no direct equivalent of `into`, but you could implement the behaviour you want easily with a generic function that knows how to combine different types of collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Clojure, you have a concrete idea (most of the time) of what kind that first collection is when you use `into`, because it changes the semantics: if it is a list, additional elements will be `conj`ed onto the front, if it is a vector, they will be `conj`ed to the back, if it is a map, you need to supply map entry designators (i. e. actual map entries or two-element vectors), sets are more flexible but also carry their own semantics.  That's why I'd guess that using `concatenate` directly, explicitly supplying the type, is probably a good enough fit for many use cases.

Other than that, I think that it could be useful to extend this functionality (Common Lisp only has a closed set of sequence types), but for that, it seems too obviously convenient to use generic functions to ignore.  It is not trivial to provide a solution that is extensible, generic, and performant.

EDIT: To summarize: no, you can't get that behaviour with clever application of one or two “built-ins”, but you can certainly write an extensible and generic solution using generic functions.

Comment: although your answer is fairly reasonable, still the question's point was a bit more specific: in clojure `into` has roughly the type `<T1 extends Seq, T2 extends Sequable>(data: T1, other: T2): T1` , in the notion of this signature it is more about 'returning the exact type, that was passed as an arg'. Maybe clojure's `empty` could be the better illustration. Moreover: in general i would narrow my question to 'returning the sequence of the same type as the sequence passed as an argument and with desired length'

Comment: It's actually not the exact type, but the type without length information, as you discovered.  You could maybe describe it as the same _class_, but that is too inexact.  For example, in Common Lisp a string is a character vector, so it is an array of rank 1 and element-type character.  So, while its  _class_ is a subclass of _array_ (e. g. `simple-array`), you can do a `(concatenate 'string …)` in Common Lisp.  Of course, Clojure doesn't generally do element-types, because (I guess) it is for one against its philosophy, but also because Java doesn't really support that (“generics“ don't work).

Answer (score 3):

ok, the only thing i've come to (besides generic methods) is this dead simple function:

```lisp
(defun into (target source)
  (let ((target-type (etypecase target
                       (vector (list 'array (array-element-type target) (*)))
                       (list 'list))))
    (concatenate target-type target source)))

CL-USER> (into (list 1 2 4) "asd")
;;=> (1 2 4 #\a #\s #\d)

CL-USER> (into #*0010 (list 1 1 0 0))
;;=> #*00101100

CL-USER> (into "asdasd" (list #\a #\b))
;;=> "asdasdab"
```

also the simple `empty` impl:

```
(defun empty (target)
  (etypecase target
    (vector (make-array 0
                        :element-type (array-element-type target)
                        :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0))
    (list)))
```

The result indeed (as [@Svante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31615/svante) noted) doesn't have the exact type, but rather "the collection with the element type being the same as that of target". It doesn't conform the clojure's protocol (where `list` target should be prepended to).

Can't see where it flaws (if it does), so would be nice to hear about that.. Anyway, as it was only for the sake of education, that will do.